# JPA Repository, specify the fetch mode for specific methods

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa

I'm using JPA and Hibernate for my Spring Project.

I created my db/entities and for some specific API I would like to improve my queries.

I think that for these, only for these specific scenarios, I need to use some joins. So, in practically, I need to have a different fetch mode (from LAZY to EAGER).

Is there a way to specify the fetch mode into my JPA repository for a specific method? Or have I to write the JPQL queries (or Criteria queries)?

Comment: Pretty sure you'd have to use Criteria Queries or similar. Are you looking for an annotation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Named entity graphs to control fetch mode in any level of the object graph.